# Magento Configurable Product are not showing in the category list?

Tags: magento

I have Configurable Product that contain small size and large size. i did all the steps in this article http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product .

it worked well and i can access the product directly.

the small problem is that it not show in the Category. 
I'm sure of the the next points.

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a
   stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through
   Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your Cache / Indices.

what to do else ? =(

Answer (score 3):

Did you use the Organic Internet extension which is the SimpleCOnfigurableProducts? If so, the simplest fix will be to make changes on this file `app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php`

From:

```
$select->columns(array(
            'entity_id'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.entity_id'),
            'customer_group_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.customer_group_id'),
            'website_id'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('cw.website_id'),
            'tax_class_id'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tax_class_id'),
            'orig_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.price'),
            'price'             => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'min_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'max_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'tier_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
            'base_tier'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price')
        ));
```

To:

```
$select->columns(array(
            'entity_id'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.entity_id'),
            'customer_group_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.customer_group_id'),
            'website_id'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('cw.website_id'),
            'tax_class_id'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tax_class_id'),
            'orig_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.price'),
            'price'             => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'min_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'max_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
            'tier_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
            'base_tier'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
            'group_price'       => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.group_price'),
            'base_group_price'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.group_price')
        ));
```

And...

From:

```
$outerSelect->columns(array(
    'customer_group_id',
    'website_id',
    'tax_class_id',
    'orig_price',
    'price',
    'min_price',
    'max_price'     => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(inner.max_price)'),
    'tier_price',
    'base_tier',
    #'child_entity_id'
));
```

To:

```
 $outerSelect->columns(array(
        'customer_group_id',
        'website_id',
        'tax_class_id',
        'orig_price',
        'price',
        'min_price',
        'max_price'     => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(inner.max_price)'),
        'tier_price',
        'base_tier',
        'group_price',
        'base_group_price' 
        #'child_entity_id'
    ));
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Even I was not able to do it earlier (now solved). I had two attributes: shape and size (earlier to be applied to selected products: configurable products). The shape and size attributes were said to be only applied to "configurable products" not "simple products" (this was the problem!).

The associated products that we create (from configurable products) are actually simple products. So Magento requires the attributes we created for the creating configurable products should be with "Simple Products" option.

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Size > Apply to > Selected Product Types > Simple Product

Then this attribute can be used to create attribute set and that in turn to create a configurable product (and this is used to create simple associated products).

Please make sure the product attributes are applied to "simple products" in the Manage Attributes section of the admin.